# What would be the best approach for fetch, transform and update data in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

We have a requirement where we need to pull data from multiple rest API services transform it and populate it into new database. There would be huge amount of records that might have to be fetched, transformed and updated this way. But it is one time activity once all the data that we get from rest calls have been transformed and populated into new DB we would not have to re run the transformation anytime later. What is the best way to achieve in spring.

Can spring batch be possible solution if it has to be a one time execution?

Comment: You have to run it once.  Just write the simplest code you can so that you're 100% sure it'll work, and leave it to run.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a one-time thing I wouldn't bother using Spring Batch. I would simply call the external APIs, get the data, transform it and then persist it in your database. You could trigger the process either by exposing an endpoint in your own API to start it or relying on a Scheduled task.

Keeping things as simple as possible (but never simpler) is one of the greatest assets you can have while developing software but it is also one of the hardest thing to achieve for us as software engineers simply because we usually overthink the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, it will be better if you use the ETL (extract, transfer, and load) tool or framework, my recommendation is Kafka check this link, I think it will be helpful [Link](https://hevodata.com/learn/setting-up-kafka-etl-2-easy-methods/)